# How to print error if non integer is entered?

Tags: java, integer, println

The program tells the user whether in integer entered is zero, positive and even or odd, or negative and even or odd.

My issue is I would like to add in a println for an error if a non integer is entered. Look at the last line.

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

public class IntegerCheck {
  public static void main(String [] args) {

    int x;
    System.out.println("Enter an integer value:");

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    x = in.nextInt();
    //String x = in.nextInt();

   if (((x % 2) == 0) && (x< 0))
     System.out.println(x + " is a negative, even integer.");
   else if (((x % 2) == 0) && (x == 0))
  System.out.println(x + " is Zero.");
   else if ((x % 2)==0) 
     System.out.println(x + " is a positive, even integer.");

   if (((x % 2) != 0) && (x<0))
     System.out.println(x + " is a negative, odd integer.");
   else if ((x % 2) != 0)
     System.out.println(x + " is a positive, odd integer.");

   if (x != 'number') 
     System.out.println(x + " is not an integer.");


}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `InputMismatchException` thrown by `Scanner.nextInt()`. Surround the code in `try`/`catch` block and catch a `InputMismatchException`. It will look something like -

```
try{
x = in.nextInt();

if (((x % 2) == 0) && (x< 0))
     System.out.println(x + " is a negative, even integer.");
   else if (((x % 2) == 0) && (x == 0))
  System.out.println(x + " is Zero.");
   else if ((x % 2)==0) 
     System.out.println(x + " is a positive, even integer.");

   if (((x % 2) != 0) && (x<0))
     System.out.println(x + " is a negative, odd integer.");
   else if ((x % 2) != 0)
     System.out.println(x + " is a positive, odd integer.");
}
catch(InputMismatchException e){
    System.out.println("You did not enter an integer!");
}
```